# Function satisfying CR equations but not differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f(z)=||z|^2 -1|^2$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at 0 and 1 only.

I find that the Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied at the origin and at all points on the unit circle. I am able to prove differentiability at the origin. But I am not able to prove differentiability at 1 and non differentiability at all points $z\ne1$ on the unit circle. Please help.

Comment: This function is differentiable at all points on the unit circle. May be it should be $f(z) = |z^2 - 1|^2$? Also, to show $\mathbb{C}$-differentiability of function remember that it's equivalent to $\mathbb R$-differentiability + CR equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments have already pointed out, the the function you wrote is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable at all points on the unit circle. This is fairly straight-forward to check using the limit definition. Let $w$ be a point on the unit circle, so $|w|=1$. Then $|z-w|\geq ||z|-|w||=||z|-1|$ by reverse-triangle inequality. Thus
$$\frac{||z|-1|}{|z-w|}\leq 1.$$
Since $f(z) = |(|z|-1)(|z|+1)|^2$ and $f(w) = 0$ we have
$$\left|\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}\right| = \frac{|(|z|-1)(|z|+1)|^2}{|z-w|}\leq ||z|-1|\cdot(|z|+1)^2.$$
Since the right-hand side tends to $0$ as $z\to w$, we conclude by squeeze theorem that $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable at $w$ and $f'(w)=0$.